# Jquery ajax not hitting the controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, knockout.js

I have come a very weird problem . Here it goes.

I am using a knockout js application speaking to webapi controller and service layers and so on.

I have kendo grid , in that after editing a row ,calling an event in the page , and within the event making an ajax call to send data to webapi controller.

Now the interesting thing is when I put breakpoint in .js file and put F12 , the control is coming to the controller otherwise it is just skipping away. Not sure what is happening at all.

the ajax code is:

```
$.ajax({
         url:controller,
         type:"PUT",
         data:"em",
         datatype:'json',
         success:function(result){
}
});

[HttpPut]
[OdataRoute("PutDataController")]
public async Taask<string> PutDataController(HttpRequestMessage par)
{
 //Do something
}
```

I tried giving 'async' : false also, but it dint work

Comment: So, you are saying that the request isn't being made? Are you sure you have the right URL? Did you enable CORS?

Comment: if you're using a tomcat server, PUT isn't enabled by default

Answer (score 1):

You should add an error function to that ajax call, so you can get access to the exception.

```
var form = $("#form");
var data = form.serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: form.attr('action'),
    type: form.attr('method'),
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (message) {
        alert("GREAT!");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert("Error: " + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the data as an object and not as a string:

```
$.ajax({
         url:controller,
         type:"PUT",
         data: {myvar: "em"},
         datatype:'json',
         success:function(result){}
});
```

Use `data: {myvar: "em"}` instead of `data:"em"`.